# PostgreSQL row diff timestamp, and calculate stddev for group

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an ID column called *mmsi* and another column of *timestamp*, with multiple timestamps per mmsi.

For each mmsi I want to calculate the standard deviation of the difference between consecutive timestamps.

I'm not very experienced with SQL but have tried to construct a function as follows:

```
SELECT 
mmsi, stddev(time_diff)
FROM
(SELECT mmsi,
 EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp - lag(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY mmsi ASC, timestamp ASC)))   
 FROM ais_messages.ais_static
 ORDER BY mmsi ASC, timestamp ASC) AS time_diff
 WHERE time_diff IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mmsi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks on the right track, but it has several problems.  You labelled your subquery, which looks almost right, with an alias which you then select.  But this subquery returns multiple rows and columns so this doesn't make any sense.  Here is a corrected version:

```
SELECT 
    t.mmsi,
    STDDEV(t.time_diff) AS std
FROM
(
    SELECT
        mmsi,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp - LAG(timestamp) OVER
                (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY timestamp))) AS time_diff 
    FROM ais_messages.ais_static
    ORDER BY mmsi, timestamp
) t
WHERE t.time_diff IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.mmsi
```

This approach should be fine but there is one edge case where it might not behave as expected.  If a given `mmsi` group have only one record, then it would not even appear in the result set of standard deviations.  This is because the `LAG` calculation would return `NULL` for that single record and it would be filtered off.